# How to set temporary halt after C-x C-c?

Tags: quitting, timers

If I run `C-x C-c` in emacs, it will close immediately. If I set `confirm-kill-emacs` to `y-or-n-p` it  will ask for confirmation before closing.

Instead of `y-or-n-p`, I want to set some temporary timer for 3 seconds before closing emacs. So, if I press `C-x C-c` it should show something like

> Emacs will be shutdown in 3 seconds. Press **C-g** to stop

If I don't do anything, it should shutdown emacs, but if I press `C-g`, it should prevent shutting down.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can roll your own predicate function that waits for 3 seconds and invariably returns non-nil (unless it is interrupted with <kbd>C-g</kbd>):

```lisp
(setq confirm-kill-emacs
      (lambda (&rest args)
        (interactive)
        (message "Quitting in 3 seconds. Press `C-g' to stop.")
        (sleep-for 3)
        t))
```

or a variant which will read any key:

```lisp
(setq confirm-kill-emacs
      (lambda (&rest args)
        (interactive)
        (null (read-event "Quitting in 3 seconds. Hit any key to stop."
                          nil 3))))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `sit-for` instead of using `sleep-for` plus `t`.
And the function need not be a command (`interactive`).

`sit-for` returns `t` if it waited and `nil` if the user interrupted the wait.

```el
(setq confirm-kill-emacs
      (lambda (&rest _)
        (message "Quit in 3 sec (`C-g' or other action cancels)")
        (sit-for 3)))
```